# Expected Array, got Object warning when a Laravel collection that starts with non-zero index is returned

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In my laravel+vue application, I am returning a filtered collection:

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::all();
    $filteredOrders = $orders->filter(function($order){
        return $order->hasLoggedInUserFromDeliveryEnd();
    });
    return $filteredOrders;       
}
```

And in the client-side, I am using a [vuetify datatable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) to populate the data:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.order_code }}</td>
</template>
```

When the collection returns a properly indexed (meaning that it has zeroth index) collection, the data is displayed properly but if it is not a properly indexed collection, then I get the following error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected
>   Array, got Object.
>
> found in
>
> ---> < VDataTable>

How do I make the collection look like an array and not an object?

Comment: WIth `array_values` I presume.

Comment: first give it a check what does the output look like. you can use `dd($filteredOrders)` or use the browsers network tab.

Comment: @u_mulder I get this error: `array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try and use `toArray` on the filtered results to make sure you always get an array, like so: `filter(...)->toArray()`.

EDIT: If you want to reset the indices, you can use `->values()` which does exactly that and converts the results to array.

Comment: Are you sure that it will be zero-indexed array?

Comment: You can try and use `->values()` for the zero-indexed arrays